# How to implement a rich label in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, c#-3.0, richtextbox, label

Amazon has an address correction feature and I want to implement something similar.

[image]

One problem I ran into is how to create a label that supports different formatting (like in the image).

I could plunk down a browser control or a richtextbox control, but that seems like a massive overkill.  Is there something simpler?  Maybe an implementation of RichLabel Lite (I just made this up).

Comment: Did you look at the html for that page?  Is each comma seperated piece a different element (like div, span etc..)?  If not then perhaps just add the formatting to each element when you build the entire line?

Comment: @AngryHacker: Is it for WinForms or ASP.NET? Please edit the title accordingly?

Comment: @tommieb75.  Do you not see the title?

Comment: Fair enough but the confusion arose when you used a web screenshot which would lead into thinking it's for a website..

Comment: @tommieb75.  Ahh, got it.  Fair enough.